# Can I ignore Unexpected reserved word error by eslint-loader

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs, eslint

I am using the newest React, Babel, and hence their necessary presets,too.
My apps works correctly and does not spit any console error.
However, I get the following error from `eslint-loader`.
how could i resolve this issue?

**my console**

```
blog git:(master) ✗ webpack -w -d
Hash: 96cef29fd40f9ab86ee5
Version: webpack 1.12.9
Time: 1305ms
        Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
    bundle.js  3.75 kB       0  [emitted]  main
bundle.js.map  2.07 kB       0  [emitted]  main
    + 1 hidden modules

ERROR in ./app/assets/frontend/app.jsx

/Users/seoyoochan/dev/blog/app/assets/frontend/app.jsx
  1:2  error  Parsing error: Unexpected reserved word

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
entry: "./app/assets/frontend/app.jsx",
output: {
    path: __dirname + "/app/assets/javascripts",
    filename: "bundle.js"
},
resolve: {
  extensions: ["", ".js", ".jsx"]
},
module: {
  preLoaders: [
    {
      test: /.jsx?$/,
      loader: "eslint-loader",
      exclude: /bundle\.js$/
    }
  ],
  loaders: [
    {
      test: /.jsx?$/,
      loader: "babel",
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      query: {
        cacheDirectory: true,
        presets: ["es2015", "react"]
      }
    }
  ]
}
};
```

**app.jsx**

```
class App extends React.Component {

      render() {
        return (<h1>hello !</h1>);
      }
    }

    let documentReady = () => {
      ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
    };

    $(documentReady);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I configured eslint to understand jsx, so here is the step-by-step solution for this error.

1. create a .elintrc file with the following

   {
     "ecmaFeatures": {
         "jsx": true
     }
   }
2. add the following in webpack.config.js

   module.exports = {
   ...
     module: {
        preLoaders: [
          {
            test: /.js?$/,
            loader: "eslint-loader",
            exclude: /bundle.js$/
          }
        ],
        loaders: [
          {
            test: /.jsx?$/,
            loader: "babel",
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            query: {
              cacheDirectory: true,
              presets: ["es2015", "react"]
            }
          }
        ]
      },
     eslint: {
        configFile: './.eslintrc'
     }
   }

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to configure eslint to understand jsx. Create a `.eslintrc`  file with the following:

```
{
  "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
  }
}
```

For the full list of configs which may throw errors for you in the future, [see the docs](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring.html)

Comment: i set it up and added `eslint: { configFile: './.eslintrc' }` but it's still the same. I fixed it when i changed `test : /.jsx?$/` in preLoaders to `test : /.js?$/`